# ASUSTOR AS604T Network configuration issue after upgrading to ADM 3.4.2.R932

Tags: nas

After upgrading my ASUSTOR NAS to latest ADM an annoying dialog "Configuration file error.(Ref. 5006)" keeps popping up every time : service-> WebDAV, Web Server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzq8T.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsfel.jpg)

And Photo Gallery, net2ftp, phpMyAdmin app doesn't work.

Apparently no other inconvenience, but before before re-initializing the entire NAS I wish to find a less radical solution.

Logifle show no relevant error and, apparently if you are quick enough to close the warning dialog you can even change the configuration.